# Clipping Basemap using shapefile as clip feature in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, clip, basemap, error-000840, living-atlas

I am trying to isolate the United States from the rest of the world using a provided basemap in ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to use a shapefile of the United States I obtained from the living atlas as the Clip Feature. When I open the clip geoprocessing tool the basemap does not appear in any of the drop downs. When I drag the basemap to the input I am given the error 000840 which states:

> The value is not a Feature Layer.

Is there anyway around this or are basemaps not editable?

Comment: Basemaps are tiled images not local to your machine. While it may be possible, it is usually a license violation to copy a basemap without authorization.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of clipping to create a new clipped dataset you may be able to meet your requirements by using a visual clip instead, as described at [Clip layers in a map](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/clip-layers-in-a-map.htm):

> You can visually clip the layers in a map to highlight an area of
> interest without altering data. You specify either a rectangular
> extent or a shape derived from features, and your map draws only
> within that extent or shape. You can clip all the layers in the map,
> or just a subset.